# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionScene$Transition.getStartConstraintSetId()' on a null object refer

Tags: android, android-motionlayout, android-motionscene

While I was working in motion layout. I got an error saying

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionScene$Transition.getStartConstraintSetId()' on a null object reference

[image: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionScene$Transition.getStartConstraintSetId()' on a null object reference]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Community Here we don't have much code. If you compare line number 107 and 102 you can see the difference. I wrote Transition to Transitionr due to this am getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

In the MotionScene I was not writing the spelling of Transition properly. As you can see in line number 107 i was writing Transitionr instead of Transition.